# Pyomo/CPLEX: Stop solution written to file 'C:\Users\...\...\tmp4ge49sy8.cplex.sol' for CPLEX API in Pyomo in Python

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cplex, pyomo

For default settings with CPLEX API in pyomo in python, after each run, a solution file is written to the drive (e.g., "C:\Users...\Temp\tmp4ge49sy8.cplex.sol"). My question is how to set up the CPLEX parameter in pyomo in python to stop this.

The reason why I want to do this is that I need to rerun the model multiple times (e.g., 1000 times), and for each run I only write down the objective value. Therefore, writing a sol file per run is not useful to me, and is time consuming.

Here are codes for the optimization model I developed:

```
class Farmers_Model(AbstractModel):
    def __init__(self):
        AbstractModel.__init__(self)
        #set
        self.FIELDS = pyo.Set()
        self.SCENARIOS = pyo.Set()
        self.PRODS = pyo.Set()
        self.SUSTAINABILITY = pyo.Set()
        #parameters
        self._area = pyo.Param(self.FIELDS, domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals) #acre
        self._unit_cost_scenario = pyo.Param(self.SCENARIOS, domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals) #$/acre
        self._inconvience_cost = pyo.Param(domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals) #$/acre
        self._yield = pyo.Param(self.FIELDS, self.SCENARIOS, self.PRODS, domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals) #tons
        self._price_for_biofuel = pyo.Param(self.PRODS, domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals) #$/tons
        self._price_for_other = pyo.Param(self.PRODS, domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals) #$/tons
        self._conversion_rate = pyo.Param(self.PRODS, domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals) #gallons/ton
        self._biofuel_demand = pyo.Param(domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals, mutable = True) #gallons
        self._sustainability = pyo.Param(self.FIELDS, self.SCENARIOS, self.SUSTAINABILITY, domain = pyo.Reals)
        self._sustainability_cost = pyo.Param(self.SUSTAINABILITY, domain = pyo.Reals, mutable = True) #$/tons additional subsidy for product for biofuel production
        #decisions
        self.Scenario_Implement = pyo.Var(self.FIELDS, self.SCENARIOS, bounds = (0, 1), domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals) #if scenario is chosen
        self.Production_for_biofuel = pyo.Var(self.FIELDS, self.PRODS, domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals)
        self.Production_for_other = pyo.Var(self.FIELDS, self.PRODS, domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals)
    

        def obj_expression(m):
            return sum(sum(m._price_for_biofuel[k] * m.Production_for_biofuel[i,k] + m._price_for_other[k] * m.Production_for_other[i,k] for k in m.PRODS) - 
                   sum(m._unit_cost_scenario[s] * m._area[i] * m.Scenario_Implement[i,s] for s in m.SCENARIOS) for i in m.FIELDS) + sum(sum(sum(m._sustainability_cost[n] * m._sustainability[i,s,n] for n in m.SUSTAINABILITY) * m._area[i] * m.Scenario_Implement[i,s] for s in m.SCENARIOS) for i in m.FIELDS)
    
        self.OBJ = pyo.Objective(rule = obj_expression, sense = pyo.maximize)
    
        @self.Constraint(self.FIELDS)
        def constraint_non_negative_profit(m, I):
            return sum(m._price_for_biofuel[k] * m.Production_for_biofuel[i,k] + 
                   m._price_for_other[k] * m.Production_for_other[i,k] for k in m.PRODS) - sum(m._unit_cost_scenario[s] * m._area[i] * m.Scenario_Implement[i,s] for s in m.SCENARIOS) >= 0
    
        @self.Constraint(self.FIELDS)
        def constraint_select_scenario(m, I):
            return sum(m.Scenario_Implement[i, s] for s in m.SCENARIOS) == 1
    
        @self.Constraint(self.FIELDS, self.PRODS)
        def constraint_split_production(m, i, k):
            return m.Production_for_biofuel[i, k] + m.Production_for_other[i, k] == sum (m._yield[i, s, k] * m.Scenario_Implement[i, s] for s in m.SCENARIOS)
    
        @self.Constraint()
        def constraint_total_fuel_demand(m):
            return sum(sum(m._conversion_rate[k] * m.Production_for_biofuel[i, k] for k in m.PRODS) for i in m.FIELDS) == m._biofuel_demand
```

Within the Farmers_Model class, I have some functions below:

generating instance:

```
def generate_instance(self, data_file):
    data = pyo.DataPortal()
    data.load(filename=data_file, model=self)
    instance = self.create_instance(data)
    return instance
```

solve an instance:

```
def solve_instance(self, solver, instance):
    opt = pyo.SolverFactory(solver)
    results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True)
    return results
```

and get the objective value:

```
def get_OBJ_value(self, instance):
    return pyo.value(instance.OBJ)
```

In the Main file, for each run (for each segment) I simply do the following:

```
for segment in segments:
    instance = model.generate_instance("inputs/data_" + str(segment) + ".json")
    results = model.solve_instance("cplex", instance)
    print(model.get_OBJ_value(instance))
```

For each iteration, the first line is to generate the instance from the json data file, the second line is to run the model, and the last line is an example to print the objective value. The issue is the for the second line, after each run, it is writing a sol file which takes noticeable time, and I would like to prevent this.

BTW, I am a novice in Pyomo. Even though the whole program is runnable, if anyone spots bad coding pattern, please let me know. I really appreciate your comments!

Comment: You should show some of the relevant code you're currently using.

Comment: CPLEX itself doesn't write a solution file unless it is told to do so via a command or through the API. Something in pyomo must be doing this. Check the pyomo documentation, settings etc.

Comment: @AKX, I have added more codes. Thanks for the notice.